# use outer function in useEffect hook get undefined

Tags: reactjs, next.js

in `useEffect` hook i used a function to send request to api for search.
function name is `searchCharacters` and it is outside of component.
i get error
`TypeError: searchCharacters(...) is undefined` when my code excuted on that point. why? how can in fix this?

error img:
[image]

```
function Dashboard() {

const [searchParam, setSearchParam] = useState("");
const [results, setResults] = useState([]);
const [isSearching, setIsSearching] = useState(false)
const debouncedSearchTerm = useDebounce(searchParam, 500);

useEffect(  ()=> {
        if(debouncedSearchTerm){

            setIsSearching(true);
            searchCharacters(debouncedSearchTerm).then(res => {
                setIsSearching(false);
                console.log("im search result", res);
                setResults(res);
            });

        }else{

            setResults([]);

        }
    }, [debouncedSearchTerm]);
}

function searchCharacters(search){
    api.get(`client/search?q=${search}`).then(
        (res) => {
            return res.data;
        }
    ).catch( e => {
        console.log(e);
        return [];
    })
}

export default Dashboard;
```

Comment: searchCharacters function should return a promise for then to be used?

Comment: yes return promise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`searchCharacters` doesn't return a Promise to chain from. Return the `api.get` Promise chain from `searchCharacters`.

```
function searchCharacters(search) {
  return api
    .get(`client/search?q=${search}`)
    .then((res) => {
      return res.data;
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log(e);
      return [];
    });
}
```

Or slightly more succinct

```
const searchCharacters = (search) =>
  api
    .get(`client/search?q=${search}`)
    .then((res) => res.data)
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log(e);
      return [];
    });
```